# Asp.net MVC + Knockout - Single page application - Image upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC app with knockout. its a single page app. I have a functionality to upload image. I am not sure whats the best option. the problem i have is, the session is not a sticky session. Which means there is no guarantee that the request will go to the same box. The options i have tried to do image upload are

1.)Data uri - I have created a custom knockout binding for image upload which posts a form to the MVC controller and the controller converts the image to a base64 string and i set the response to a viewmodel property in JS and binding to img tag. While this seemed to be the best solution, i had to support IE8 and this dint work work in IE8 as IE8 has limitation for Data URI

2.)Storing the image in temp folder in application server - Since sticky session is not available this wont work reliably

3.)Store the image in session - This seems to be non performant as session would end up hogging memory

Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1) This option is cool for session problems, but you will have a really big overhead in transfer (every image you will send to client and back multiple times).

Ad 2) You can store image in temp folder in unique subfolder (for example with GUID name), and send to client only this GUID. Of course you will have to provide solution which will for time to time clean up this folder - but this is quite easy.

Ad 3)If you store your session in memory, your Web server will quite fast "blow up" with out of memory exception.

So in my option the best option is 2, because:

1. You will save transfer, so your site will work faster for client
2. It is quite easy to implement
3. It is easy to manage.

Comment: Thank you for that insight. I agree with point 1 and 3. But point 2 not sure how its going to solve the sticky session issue. May be i am missing something? Option 2 is good if sticky sessions are in use. But if sticky sessions are not in use then it becomes a problem right?

Comment: Instead of sending whole image to client and back, you just send temporary id which you store on filesystem

Comment: Yes. So if i do that and set the src of image to that path with GUID then the browser is going to make another to retrieve that image. There is no guarantee that the request will go the box where the image is stored.

Comment: Do you have a cloud app? If yes try to store image on blob. If not please describe more how your solution is working